# relation between minimal polynomial and jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I just solved some exercises on minimal polynomials and i remember that there is a relation between the minimal polynomial and the jordan normal form.

But my question is the following : knowing the minimal polynomial of a given matrix $A$ what information can we get about the jordan normal form (without computing it).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82607/why-does-the-largest-jordan-block-determine-the-degree-for-that-factor-in-the-mi?rq=1  has some information. I'm not sure there's much more you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicity of an eigenvalue in the minimal polynomial is the size of that eigenvalue's largest Jordan block.  See the ["Complex matrices"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Complex_matrices) topic in Wikipedia article "Jordan normal form."