# Given eigenvalues and eigenvector, how to find the matrix there are fewer eigenvectors than its rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know of the $A = PDP^{-1}$
formula but it only works if P is invertible.

My example I've spent hours on is:

Find a 3x3 matrix where the only eigenvector is $
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
for which the eigenvalue is 1. (Any constant multiplication of the eigenvector is naturally fine as well).

One example is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
-1/2 & 1/2 & 3/2
\end{bmatrix}.

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get to this answer.

Comment: You have a solution.....   to go backwards,   name your matrix $M$ and find a matrix $Q$  such that $Q^{-1}  MQ = J$  is in Jordan form. With eigenvalue $1,$  the right hand column of $Q$  is a column vector $q_3$   such that $(M_I)^3 q_3 = 0$  **BUT**  $(M_I)^2 q_3  \neq 0.$  Next  $q_2 = (M_I) q_3 $  and then  $q_1 = (M_I) q_2 =  (M_I)^2 q_3  $  That is your matrix $Q,$   columns $q_1, q_2, q_3$   If you switch the order  to $q_3, q_2, q_1$  the outcome of $Q^{-1}  MQ $  is the transpose of $J$

Answer (score 2):

in the U.S., Jordan form  is upper triangular. The transformation with characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^3 $  but minimal polynomial the same is just the Jordan block

$$ 
J=
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

That was the hard part. Now, you want to switch the eigenvector

$$ e_1 =
 \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
1  \\ 
0  \\ 
0  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
for the required

$$ v =
 \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
1  \\ 
1  \\ 
0  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

That is, you need to pull back $v$   to $e_1$  You require an (invertible)  matrix $R$   such that

$$ 
 \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
1  \\ 
0  \\ 
0  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) \; =  \; \;
R  \; \; 
 \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
1  \\ 
1  \\ 
0  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
so write out the system. My first try was lower triangular so it is easy to confirm the nonzero determinant,

$$ R=
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Note the eigenvectors of $R$ do not matter .  Next

$$ R^{-1}=
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
as we can confirm by calculating $R^{-1}  R$

Finally, the matrix similar to $J,$  and an answer to your problem, is
$$  R^{-1} J  R  $$

Things you should know:  similar matrices have the same characteristic and minimal polynomials; I believe the proof for the characteristic polynomial has several steps. The minimal has a one line proof:  for any one variable polynomial $f(x),$  we have $f(Q^{-1}  M Q ) = Q^{-1}  f(M) Q.$  Thus, if $f(M) = 0$  we also have $f(Q^{-1}  M Q ) = 0$

Next, **with just one** eigenvalue, the degree of the minimal  polynomial is the size of the largest Jordan block. see

[Why does the largest Jordan block determine the degree for that factor in the minimal polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82607/why-does-the-largest-jordan-block-determine-the-degree-for-that-factor-in-the-mi)

and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Complex_matrices

ADDED  I thought of a good display for the "largest block" idea.

$$  
M =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

The characteristic polynomial  is $(x-1)^2 (x-2)^2 (x-3)^2 .$  This is also the minimal polynomial;  that says that each eigenvalue gets a Jordan block of size 2.

Meanwhile, $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = x^3 - 6 x^2 + 11 x - 6  $  and

$$  
M^3 - 6 M^2 + 11 M - 6 I =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
which is not the zero matrix, indeed there is something nonzero in each of the three blocks